# check if string1 contains string2 without knowing which is 1 or 2

Tags: javascript

In javascript, given a string "body" and another string "bodyguard", How can I return `true` since one string is part of the other with out knowing their order of presentation to the code? i.e.
`let string1 = 'body', string2 = 'bodyguard'` or
`let string1 = 'bodyguard', string2 = 'body'`?

And without knowing if it is the first or the last part, so long as one string is completely part of the other, without knowing which is the longer of the two.
thx

Comment: use indexOf to check for the presence of the shortest one in the longest one ? What's the difficulty exactly ?

Comment: and the check can be done with JavaScript String includes()  function.

Comment: @Take_Care_ Note that String#includes isn't available in IE, even IE11

Comment: Something like "return string1.indexOf(string2) !=-1 || string2.indexOf(string1) !=-1" would do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let string1 = 'body', string2 = 'bodyguard';
let string3 = 'bodyguard', string4 = 'body';

var controlString=function(str1,str2){
  return (str1.indexOf(str2)!==-1||str2.indexOf(str1)!==-1);
};
console.log(controlString(string1,string2));
console.log(controlString(string3,string4));
```

Answer (score 4):

Just check both ways:

```
if (str1.includes(str2) || str2.includes(str1)) {
    // It's one of them
}
```

Or always check the longer one for the shorter one

```
let [longer, shorter] = str1.length > str2.length ? [str1, str2] : [str2, str1];
if (longer.includes(shorter) != -1) {
    // It's one of them
}
```

*(You used `let`, so I assume it's okay to use destructuring assignment and `String#includes`, as all are ES2015+.)*

If you don't want to use `String#includes`, though, `str.indexOf(otherStr) != -1` does effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if either string contains the other (not tested but should work):

```
if ((string1.indexOf(string2) !== -1) || (string2.indexOf(string1) !== -1)){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in Javascript :

```
var string1 = "body";
var string2 = "bodyguard";
if(string1.includes(string2) || string2.includes(string1)){
    // DO WHAT YOU WANT
}   else {

}
```

```js
var string1 = "body";
var string2 = "bodyguard";
if(string1.includes(string2) || string2.includes(string1)){
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "One string is part of another" ;
} else {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No string is part of another" ;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: With other strings it can be, in my exact example never :)